# Downgrade Ventura 13.3.1 to Ventura 13.1

Tags: install, ventura

My new Mac Mini M2 has Ventura 13.3.1 pre-installed. To troubleshoot [a problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459761/444758), I would like to downgrade to Ventura 13.1.

To try that, I created a bootable USB stick with Ventura 13.1. However, the installer requires an active internet connection. And guess what... during the install it automatically downloads the latest version 13.3.1 and ignores version 13.1 on the USB stick.

How can I install 13.1? Can I somehow force an offline install? Can I block the automatic upgrade?

Comment: Alternatively, 13.4 is expected next week, which does include fixes for Bluetooth connectivity.

Comment: @benwiggy good to know. Fingers crossed...